# Webflow: host security.txt at .well-known

Tags: security, webflow, devsecops, security.txt

How can I host a `/.well-known/security.txt` file in Webflow?

I tried to set up a 301 redirect from `/.well-known/security.txt` to another path, but I get the error:

```
Invalid .well-known request
```

Does someone know another way to host the `security.txt` file on Webflow? Thank you in advance!